# Get an R Shiny Server from .globals

Tags: r, scope, shiny, webserver, global

If we look at the implementation of the shinyServer function, it's not too hard to see that it just inserts the passed function into what I presume is the global environment. However, I haven't seen the global environment referred to as ".globals" before and only as ".GlobalEnv" or "globalenv()".

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer
#> function (func) 
#> {
#>     .globals$server <- list(func)
#>     invisible(func)
#> }
#> <environment: namespace:shiny>
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the function implicitly passed to the shinyServer function from wherever it is being assigned to. I've been looking in the global environment, but I don't see a `server` object there after using the shinyServer function. Where is `.globals` and how do I access it and its contents including `.globals$server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.globals` is a separate environment. You can see the code for it on github [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/globals.R).

If you want to know what goes in it try:
`ls(shiny:::.globals, all.names=T)`

You get:

> ls(shiny:::.globals)
>    [[1](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/globals.R)] "clients"          "domain"           "IncludeWWW"       "lastPort"         "options"          "ownSeed"          "resources"
>    [8] "reterror"         "retval"           "running"          "serverInfo"       "showcaseDefault"  "showcaseOverride" "stopped"
>   [15] "testMode"

The actual values are dynamic. Here is a little app which will show you what values are currently in the `.globals`.

```
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    h3("What's in globals?"),
    selectInput(inputId="globin",label="Parts of .globals", choices=ls(shiny:::.globals)),
    textOutput('glob')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    x<-sys.frame(1)
    output$glob <- renderPrint(mget(input$globin, env=x$.globals))
  }
))
```

I got all of the environments into `x` using `sys.frame(1)` and then just subset `.globals` from there.

Comment: This looks in part like what I need, but I still don't know how to access this environment. I would think that I could `library(shiny); ls('package:shiny', all.names=T); ls(all.names=T)` and at least one of these would contain `.globals` but I do not see it there. How can I access `.globals` and its contents?

Comment: @ctesta01 Added more to the answer to address your quesitons.

Comment: Cool! Very neat answer. Thanks for the app example.